# Unable to fetch UITableView Footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to change the background color of the Footer of a `UITableView` section. However, I'm not having any luck.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i]];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = [_tableView footerViewForSection:i];
[header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

The first part - where I set the colors in the cell - is working. The second part - where I want to set the footer color - isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the color inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and inside the `footerViewForSection` method.

The table view will request cells, headers and footers as it needs them. For cells, chances are it will reuse the same cell which is why you cell color seems to work. However if you do some scrolling you will find it probably stops working.

Your header view does not work because you are asking for a view in your code, but that will not be the same view the table uses as it will have asked for its own.

So you should set the colors when the cell, header or footer is being requested.

Ideally the cell/header/footer configurations should be driven from your data model. e.g. Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should create the cell appropriate for the data model entry for the index path. Sets its color based on the color required by the data model entry. All changes then are done on the data model and you reload the affected sections and/or rows.

Comment: And so it's impossible to change the footer color afterwards? I've already set a backgroundcolor in `footerViewForSection`, but I'd like to change it after an action.

Comment: As noted in updated answer, change the data model and reload the affected indexPath. Everything will then just update on its own. So add a state for each entry which defines the color it should be for example.

Answer (score 0):

Is `-footerViewForSection:` returning a value? My guess is it's returning `nil`. Are you providing the footer view to the table view in the delegate methods? If you're not, it doesn't exist. If you are, you can set the color then.

Comment: And so it's impossible to change the footer color afterwards? I've already set a backgroundcolor in `footerViewForSection`, but I'd like to change it after an action.

Comment: You've set a background color in -footerViewForSection:, or in -tableView:viewForFooterInSection:? It's not clear whether you've created the footer for the table view in the -tableView:viewForFooterInSection: delegate callback.